# Detecting "noise" in a video stream ("snow", green blocks, partial frame distortion etc.)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I am on OpenCV 2.4.1 and need to detect if a video stream has any kind of noise. Noise such as the sample frames shown below:

What might be a simple, quick way to detect these kinds of noise. The issue is this noise could be intermittent, unpredictable and need detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple image subtraction. [Subtract](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract) two [successing frames](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#queryframe). Find the [mean](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) of this result. If it is not close to zero, then you have your noise.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I also have some moving objects in the frames, wouldn't those be marked as noise as well?

Comment: Then take the threshold high. Also, if you have your noises like these ones, then you are going to have too many equal pixel values. I mean, over half of the noise images' pixels are going to be equal. You can use this fact, too.